# Flutter: How to disable the past dates in `showDatePicker`?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

How to disable the past dates in flutter `showDatePicker` ? Below is my code

```
DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                              context: context,
                              initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                              firstDate: DateTime(2020, 1),
                              lastDate: DateTime(2101));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try out this

```
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
  lastDate: DateTime(2100),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

> **initialDate** : Default Selected Date In Picker Dialog
>
> **firstDate** : From Minimum Date Of Your Date Picker
>
> **lastDate** : Max Date Of To-Date Of Date Picker
>
> You can select date between from first date and last date

```
 DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                                  lastDate: DateTime(2101));
```